# 405 method not allowed error when trying to post to web service

Tags: asp.net, jquery, wcf, json

I borrowed the following code to try to make an ajax-enabled WCF service work since I kept getting the 405 method not allowed error:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AjaxWcf.svc/ConnectionTest",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{"name":"Elemenex"}',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
      alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: AjaxFailed
  });

  function AjaxFailed(result) {
    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
  }
});
```

In the service code-behind I have the following:

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST")> _

Public Function ConnectionTest(ByVal name As String) As String
    Return String.Format("Hello {0}", name)
End Function
```

I have seen searched up & down the net all day today trying to find what the issue could be. I have seen posts where `.svc` isn't mapped with the POST verb in IIS. It isn't on my development PC but it is on the server. Both give the 405 errors.

Could this have something to do with the verbs being allowed in the `web.config`?

I have a beautiful site going so far & having this work (and soon) will really make a good impression.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this attribute to your method:

```
ScriptMethodAttribute
```

Comment: This is worked for the example & with some tweaking also for what I needed to work as well...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this line inside your `web.config` service model?

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```